# ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' None'

Tags: python, type-conversion, valueerror

i got a error with python code.

this is a part of my code(sba2.py).

```
rna_list=[]
qc_rna=[]
atac_list=[]
qc_atac=[]

for i in range(rna_seq.index.stop):
    rna_list.append(list(rna_seq.iloc[i,:].dropna()))

def str_to_list(str_input):
    str_list = str_input[1:-1].split(',')
    new_list=[]
    new_list.append(int(str_list[0]))
    new_list.append(float(str_list[1]))  (line 23)
    return(new_list)

for j in range(len(rna_list)):
    li=[]
    for i in range(len(rna_list[j])):
        li.append(str_to_list(rna_list[j][i]))    (line 29)
    qc_rna.append(li)
```

and i got a error like this.

```
  File "sba2.py", line 29, in <module>
    li.append(str_to_list(rna_list[j][i]))
  File "sba2.py", line 23, in str_to_list
    new_list.append(float(str_list[1]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' None'
```

i want to know what's the problem with this and how can i solve this error.
please let me know. thanks!

Comment: You're trying to convert `' None'` to a float, which cannot be done. Check your splitting code, something isn't splitting correctly. Try printing `str_list` to see what it actually contains.

Answer (score 0):

There is a string " None" which is present in your data. Your code is trying to convert this to float. Either replace this a float and then run the code.